# Firebase app distribution: How to add testers to tester group automatically with command?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cli, firebase-app-distribution

I am using the below Firebase command to invite testers to my Firebase app as per the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/ios/distribute-cli

```
firebase appdistribution:testers:add anothertester@email.com moretesters@email
```

We maintain two tester groups for these testers for our app. The above command only adds testers to our app's portal but not to the tester groups.

**Is there a command/way to add the testers to a particular tester group automatically?**

Things I have tried so far:

1. Tried using --group and --groups flag which are used in `firebase appdistribution:distribute` command but got the error: `unknown option '--groups'`
2. Also tried using the Firebase App distribution API POST call and getting the same result:

```
POST /v1/{project=projects/*}/testers:batchAdd
```

Comment: I'm trying to do the same, API doesn't support groups AFAIK.